# How to get lists from sharepoint site using graph api beta

Tags: sharepoint, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm following documentation from here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/sharepoint

I want to enumerate lists from default site.

1. get `siteId` using `/sharePoint/site` end point(works fine)
2. Request lists using `sharePoint/sites/{{siteId}}/lists` doesn't work returns `404` with following message

   `{
     "error": {
      "code": "itemNotFound",
       "message": "Requested site could not be found",
      "innerError": {
       "request-id": "34b1b51a-59ba-4c56-991a-319ffbe33005",
       "date": "2017-04-07T10:46:40"
     }
    }
   }`

any pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have confirmed there is a list within this site. You'll get a 404 if you attempt to fetch a list collection from a site without one.

More likely is you're using the wrong ID. The documentation is a bit ambiguous about which property it means by `{site-id}`.

When you fetch your site, there will be both a `siteId` and an `id` property. You want the `id` property. Using `siteId` will result in a 404.

```
{
    "createdDateTime": "",
    "description": "",
    "id": "**** Use this one ****",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "",
    "name": "",
    "webUrl": "",
    "root": {},
    "siteCollection": {
        "hostname": ""
    },
    "siteCollectionId": "",
    "siteId": "**** Not this one ****"
}
```

Comment: Yes I tried id property and we have a list still getting 404

Comment: Same one which I listed on question of including beta API base url

Answer (score 2):

in `sharePoint/sites/{{siteId}}/lists` the part of `{siteId}` is actually 3 part, the domain, root site id, subsite id, for for example if i have a domain `contoso.sharepoint.com`, with a site named `root site` with id `123` (it should be a guid) and another subsite under that named `Klingon Site` with id of `145` so my final `{siteId}` is `contoso.sharepoint.com,123,145`

should be like `contoso.sharepoint.com,fffdf23f-1234-1234-a744-17e2e196e777,1481eca1-4567-4567-8dbc-60c666ab3b8c`